# Save byte array as video format (.mp4) in QT Creator

Tags: qt, video

Is there any way for me to save an incoming byte array stream as a .mp4 file?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried creating a `QFile` object and saving the `QByteArray` to disk? Also, is your `QByteArray` in mp4 format as you receive it?

Comment: The video comes in over a byte stream from a live camera. Every second or so it sends a byte array which I can successfully turn into a .png

Comment: What do you mean saving to disk? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to use the `QCamera` class and `QMediaRecorder` for capturing live video.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qcamera.html
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qmediarecorder.html
http://www.meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/recording-videos-with-qt5.html